# Read from multiple text files and email to recipient

Tags: powershell, text-files, file-get-contents

I'm very new to powershell so please forgive the way I word this if it is not clear.

I have powershell command that will read a line in a text file and email it to a recipient.
As you can see in the code below it's looking for a file which conains "ama" - Which it does fine.

However, sometimes there are multiple files in the directory with "ama" in the file name. I'd like it to send an email for each file that has "ama" in the name. Either an individual email for each file, or a summary which reads the same line in all the "ama" files in the directory.

Can this be done?

Many thanks.

```
$a=Get-Content -Path "S:\Vecta\Test\*ama.*" | select -first 1 -skip 9 
$a = $a.substring(3,16)
$b = "Imported"
$msg.Body=$a

#$msg.Body=Get-Content -Path "S:\Vecta\Test\*ama.*" | select -first 1 -skip 9 |  Out-String 

#Message Subject
$msg.Subject=$b

$smtp.Send($msg)
#$attachment.Dispose();
$msg.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Setup:

```
PS S:\vecta\test> "testa" >aama.txt
PS S:\vecta\test> "testb" >bama.log
PS S:\vecta\test> "testc" >cama.csv
PS S:\vecta\test> ls


    Directory: S:\vecta\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       08.03.2016     19:11             16 aama.txt
-a----       08.03.2016     19:11             16 bama.log
-a----       08.03.2016     19:11             16 cama.csv

PS S:\vecta\test> $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "S:\Vecta\Test\*ama.*"
PS S:\vecta\test> $files.count
3

PS S:\vecta\test> foreach($file in $files){$a = get-content $file; "$file=$a"}
S:\Vecta\Test\aama.txt=testa
S:\Vecta\Test\bama.log=testb
S:\Vecta\Test\cama.csv=testc
```

As you can see the code works.

Just loop through the files:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "S:\Vecta\Test\*ama.*" 

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $a = Get-Content $file | select -first 1 -skip 9 

    # your email logic

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but get the follwing error: Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\AmaEmail.ps1:27 char:21
+     $a = Get-Content <<<<  $file | select -first 1 -skip 9 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: It works, see my example. You must've done something wrong.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work yesterday but it's doing exactly what I want now. Thanks!